# How to bypass any on board circuitry when using an external LDO

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, battery, voltage-protection

I am using an ESP8266 NodeMCU (Amica) module.  I am powering it with a 3.7v rechargeable Li-Lion battery (18650).  I am regulating the voltage using a LDO circuit. https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-voltage-regulator-lipo-and-li-ion-batteries/

I want to avoid as much on board circuitry as possible.  For example I notice that there is a non-LDO regulator (AMS1117 chip) on board.

What pin on the module should I connect the regulator output to?

Thanks.